# raster2pgsql error: "ERROR: malformed record literal: DETAIL: Missing left parenthesis."

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, raster2pgsql

This is a command I use to upload dem.tiff into PostGIS database:

```
$ raster2pgsql -a "/path/to/dem.tiff" -F test_schema.raster2 | psql -h localhost -d pisl -U postgres
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  malformed record literal: "01000 (...) 04BB04"

LINE 1: ...aci_schema"."raster2" ("rast","filename") VALUES ('010000010...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
```

I have looked on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924632/malformed-record-literal-but-the-so-called-literal-is-data-from-a-table) and [elsewhere](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D960CB61B694CF459DCFB4B0128514C206A3E0AF%40exadv11.host.magwien.gv.at) but that didn't help me very much.

Any ideas what is wrong or where to look?

Comment: A bit hard to tell without seeing the tif. Any chance of posting it?

Comment: Of course: https://imgur.com/a/HF1V9Dd

I didn't think there is anything wrong with the tiff file so didn't think of posting it.

Comment: I just tried a different TIF file but I get the same error.

Comment: I can't see any download file there.

Comment: https://ufile.io/ysufz there you go :)

Comment: Did the answer below fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the combination of the -a and -F switches. As -a means append to an existing table, it is incompatible with the -F switch, which adds a column with the filename of the raster, which is impossible if the table already exists.

If you change your statement to:

```
raster2pgsql -c "/path/to/dem.tiff" -F test_schema.raster2 
| psql -h localhost -d pisl -U postgres
```

it will work. On subsequent calls you can use -a and -F together, once the table raster2 exists or you could manually add such a column to an existing raster table.